# Javascript: element.setAttribute - Download from webmap to server instead of local machine

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, download

I have a webmap(leaflet with Draw extension) that´s set up and running on site. 
I want to export and download drawn polygon as geojson-file to a specific server. The geojson-file will afterwards be examined by a platform-based GIS program. The GIS task is working fine.

The`element.setAttribute('download', filename);` script is pretty straight forward, but can it be done instead downloading locally, to a specific server? Other solutions are appreciated.

Comment: So you want to upload a file from the user to the server? What exactly is the content you're trying to transfer?

Comment: The content would be a geojson-file with geodata in it. I want to to spatial querys on the files(s) from my server. Another approach would be upload directly to a database like postgres with postGIS. But that could be complicated and is version 2.0

Comment: So is it a user's own browser that's sending the data? Could you just make  a POST request? Or does the JS not have access to the file's data?

Comment: I was considering HTTPS POST request, but have only worked with GET request from my server done by running from python script. But if so, the user draws on the webmap and then the POST request runs. But will this storage the drawing? It needs to be data that can be examined later on.

Comment: If you set up your python server to handle the POST request, then the server can do anything it wants with sent data, including store it for later. I'd give an example, but I'm not very familiar with python... Can you edit your question to describe what type of web thing you're building, in detail?

Comment: In this project the python approach won´t be needed. But to clarify what I want: 1) Webmap(leaflet with Draw extension) that´s setup to export and download polygon as geojson-file. The geojson-file will afterwards be examined by a platform-based GIS program. The GIS task is working fine. So what I need is how i(n the most proper way) to upload the drawn items (every time a user draws) to a server where from the GIS program downloads it. Thats´s about it.

Comment: Please update your question with that info so that other people will be able to find it. The current title/description seems not immediately relevant to what you actually are asking how to do.

Comment: Also please include any relevant code, so we can see exactly what we're dealing with.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/145170) is relevant?